# HTTP client-server role reversal

Tags: python, http

I want to build a system, where a server talks to its **clients** through HTTP/RESTful API.

I.e. each client process will have an embedded HTTP server. A client will connect to the server (not necessary HTTP server) and then server will use the open socket to call HTTP methods on the client.

Is there any ready to use solution for this?

The development language is Python, but the solution can be in any language if it runs on Linux and is open source.

P.S. Here is the "why": I want to allow the server to use client's API in an easy manner, while allowing clients to traverse firewalls.

Comment: What about a websocket ?

Comment: Yes, websocket, or even wamp.ws is an option. But I want to know if there a way to go with a good old HTTP.

Comment: Biggest problem I see is that the HTTP ports are ”priviliged” i.e. usually normal client programs can not act as servers on port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) to bypass firewalls without the necessary rights to listen to ports <1024.

Comment: That's not an issue. I fully control the client box (and it's not a browser of any kind).